# combine duplicate columns into one column data frame r

Tags: r

I have data frame:

| SRR1 | SRR2 | SRR3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| NA | RS1 | RS1 |
| RS2 | NA | RS2 |
| RS3 | RS3 | RS3 |

I want to add column ID with data from column SRR1,2,3:

| ID | :---- |
| --- | --- |
| RS1 | :---- |
| RS2 | :---- |
| RS3 | :---- |

Comment: Try `df %>% mutate(ID = coalesce(SRR1, SRR2, SRR3))` where `df` is your dataframe

Comment: @KarthikS thanks for your answer! It gives me columns "SRR1.ID SRR2.ID ..."